# AWSGLUE python package - ls cannot access dir

Tags: python, etl, aws-glue

I'm trying to install local `awsglue` package for developing purpose on my local machine (Windows + Git Bash)

`https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/tree/glue-1.0`

`https://support.wharton.upenn.edu/help/glue-debugging`

`Spark` directory and `py4j` mentioned in below error does exist but still getting error

[image]
Directory from which I trigger the sh is below:

```
user@machine xxxx64~/Desktop/lm_aws_glue/aws-glue-libs-glue-1.0/bin
$ ./glue-setup.sh
ls: cannot access 'C:\Spark\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-*-src.zip': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'PyGlue.zip': No such file or directory
./glue-setup.sh: line 14: zip: command not found
```

`ls` result:

```
$ ls -l
total 7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 n1543781 1049089 135 May  5  2020 gluepyspark*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 n1543781 1049089 114 May  5  2020 gluepytest*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 n1543781 1049089 953 Mar  5 11:10 glue-setup.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 n1543781 1049089 170 May  5  2020 gluesparksubmit*
```

Comment: Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Windows + Git Bash

Comment: This does not answer your questions but if you're open to using a docker image for local Glue development, [see this aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original install code requires few tweaks and works ok. Still need a workaround for `zip`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#original code
#ROOT_DIR="$(cd $(dirname "$0")/..; pwd)"
#cd $ROOT_DIR

#re-written
ROOT_DIR="$(cd /c/aws-glue-libs; pwd)" 
cd $ROOT_DIR

SPARK_CONF_DIR=$ROOT_DIR/conf
GLUE_JARS_DIR=$ROOT_DIR/jarsv1

#original code
#PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH"
#PYTHONPATH=`ls $SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-*-src.zip`:"$PYTHONPATH"

#re-written
PYTHONPATH="/c/Spark/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/:$PYTHONPATH"
PYTHONPATH=`ls /c/Spark/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-*-src.zip`:"$PYTHONPATH"

# Generate the zip archive for glue python modules
rm PyGlue.zip
zip -r PyGlue.zip awsglue
GLUE_PY_FILES="$ROOT_DIR/PyGlue.zip"
export PYTHONPATH="$GLUE_PY_FILES:$PYTHONPATH"

# Run mvn copy-dependencies target to get the Glue dependencies locally
#mvn -f $ROOT_DIR/pom.xml -DoutputDirectory=$ROOT_DIR/jarsv1 dependency:copy-dependencies

export SPARK_CONF_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/conf
mkdir $SPARK_CONF_DIR
rm $SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf
# Generate spark-defaults.conf
echo "spark.driver.extraClassPath $GLUE_JARS_DIR/*" >> $SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf
echo "spark.executor.extraClassPath $GLUE_JARS_DIR/*" >> $SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf

# Restore present working directory
cd -
```